# Getting the mime type from a request in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, http-headers

Im learning nodejs but I ran into a roadblock. Im trying to setup a simple server that will serve static files. My problem is that unless I explicitly type in the extension in the url, I cannot get the file extension. The `httpheader 'content-type'` comes in as undefined . 
Here is my code, pretty simple:

```
var http = require("http"),
path = require("path"),
fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){

console.log([path.extname(request.url), request.headers['content-type']]);
var fileName = path.basename(request.url) || "index.html",
    filePath = __dirname + '/public/' + fileName;
console.log(filePath);

fs.readFile( filePath, function(err,data){
    if (err) throw err
    response.end(data);
});


})
server.listen(3000)
```

Any ideas? 
FYI I dont just wanna dive into `connect` or other, I wanna know whats going on before I drop the grind and go straight to modules.

Answer (score 1):

So static web servers generally don't do any deep magic. For example, nginx has a small mapping of file extensions to mime types here: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/conf/mime.types

There's likely also some fallback logic defaulting to html. You can also use a database of file "magic numbers" as is used by the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility to look at the beginning of the file data and guess based on that.

But there's no magic here. It's basically

- go by the file extension when available
- maybe go by the beginning of the file content as next option
- use a default of html because normally only html resources have URLs with no extensions, whereas images, css, js, fonts, multimedia, etc almost always do use file extensions in their URIs

Also note that browsers generally have fairly robust set of checks that will intepret files correctly even when Content-Type headers are mismatched with the actual response body data.